# How do I plot a really large heatmap using Python's pylab.figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `pylab.figure` to plot a heatmap. Nothing unusual about that and I get good results for smaller heatmap dimensions.

*Problem:* I want to plot a heatmap with about 30 rows and nearly 2000 columns. That works -- except that I cannot get the labels to render in a readable non-overlapping way.

I tried playing around with `figsize` and `dpi`, but all it does is to rescale the resulting resolution of the output image. I failed to actually make the image wide enough, so that the labels do not overlap anymore.

*Code excerpt:*

```
fig = pylab.figure(figsize = (640,30), dpi = 50)
axmatrix = fig.add_axes([ 0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.1 ])
axmatrix.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize = 8)
im = axmatrix.matshow(ordered_observations, aspect = 'auto', origin = 'lower', cmap = pylab.cm.YlGnBu)

axcolor = fig.add_axes([ 0.96, 0.1, 0.01, 0.1 ])
pylab.colorbar(im, cax = axcolor)

axmatrix.set_xticks(range(0, len(right) - 1))
axmatrix.set_yticks(range(0, len(left) - 1))
axmatrix.set_xticklabels(map(lambda name: name, list(right)[0:len(right) - 1]), rotation = 90)
axmatrix.set_yticklabels(map(lambda name: name, list(left)[0:len(left) - 1]))

fig.show()
fig.savefig('linkage.png')
```

Thanks,

Kim

EDIT: `ordered_observations` snippet:

```
[[ 0.5   0.5   0.5  ...,  0.5   0.5   0.5 ]
 [ 1.    1.    1.   ...,  0.5   0.5   0.5 ]
 [ 1.    1.    1.   ...,  0.5   0.5   0.5 ]
 ...,
 [ 0.25  0.2   0.2  ...,  0.2   0.2   0.2 ]
 [ 0.25  0.2   0.2  ...,  0.2   0.2   0.2 ]
 [ 0.25  0.2   0.2  ...,  0.2   0.2   0.2 ]]
```

This is the truncated pylab output. The real data is a 29 x 1835 matrix.

EDIT 2: Instead of depositing my data anywhere, it think it is better to generate test data via the following code snippet.

```
import numpy
import random
ordered_observations = numpy.array([ [ random.random() for column in range(0, 1835) ] for row in range(0, 29) ])
```

EDIT 3: A complete working example.

```
import numpy
import random
import pylab

left = range(0, 29)
right = range(0, 1835)
ordered_observations = numpy.array([ [ random.random() for column in range(0, 1835) ] for row in range(0, 29) ])

fig = pylab.figure(figsize = (640,30), dpi = 50)
axmatrix = fig.add_axes([ 0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.1 ])
axmatrix.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize = 8)
im = axmatrix.matshow(ordered_observations, aspect = 'auto', origin = 'lower', cmap = pylab.cm.YlGnBu)

axcolor = fig.add_axes([ 0.96, 0.1, 0.01, 0.1 ])
pylab.colorbar(im, cax = axcolor)

axmatrix.set_xticks(range(0, len(right) - 1))
axmatrix.set_yticks(range(0, len(left) - 1))
axmatrix.set_xticklabels(map(lambda name: name, list(right)[0:len(right) - 1]), rotation = 90)
axmatrix.set_yticklabels(map(lambda name: name, list(left)[0:len(left) - 1]))

fig.show()
fig.savefig('linkage.png')
```

**Workaround**

Looks like this is a tricky question, so I finally gave in and use this workaround:

- plot multiple heatmaps for spans of 200 columns

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: How about data for 'left' and 'right'? It's good to make a habit of posting runnable code.

Comment: Data and runnable code provided now. Labels are unreadable both in `fig.show()` as well as in the generated PNG.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following code to set the fontsize smaller

```
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=9)
```

But, I might not understand your problem exactly. Could you save the contents of `ordered_observations` in a file and attach it.

Comment: I do not know how to attach files here, but I edited the question to show a truncated version of my data.

Comment: You can dump your file on a website http://www.filedropper.com/ and link to it. Or, post a picture of the heatmap.

Comment: I added a code fragment for generating test data that can be used for ordered_observations.